# Excel: Converting a duration (hours, minutes, seconds) to increments of 6 minutes

Tags: excel, google-sheets, openoffice-calc

I have a spreadsheet column with durations of hours, minutes, and seconds.  For example, 0:01:00 is 1 minute.  1:06:28 is 1 hour, 6 minutes, and 28 seconds.

I'm trying to convert this data into increments of 10% of an hour (6 minutes).  So, 0:00:01 (a second) would be converted to 0.1.  0:06:00 (6 minutes) would also be 0.1.  1:12:01 (1 hour, 12 minutes and 1 second) would be 1.3.

Any ideas on how to handle this in Excel (or Google Sheets)?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Are the values in the column a text value or a number formatted as a duration?

Comment: How is 1 second 1/10 of six minutes? How is 72 minutes 1.3 times 6 minutes?

Comment: OK hopefully this is relevant: when I double click on a value that says 0:01:00 it changes it to "12:01:00 AM".  When I double click on a value that says 2:08:42 it changes it to 2:08:42 AM.  When I right click on it and do "format cell" it has a "custom" category of type "h:mm:ss".  It is a .csv file so I doubt there is anything too fancy.  If that doesn't answer your question would you please let me know how to find out what you asked?  Thanks very much!

Comment: 1 second would be 1/10 of an hour.  In other words, 6 minutes.  These are time durations where I want the end result to be in increments of 6 minutes.  So, a second is 0.1 (which stands for 10% of an hour AKA 6 minutes).  6 minutes and a second is 0.2.  Did that make sense?  Thanks!

Comment: *1 second would be 1/10 of an hour. In other words, 6 minutes*  Huh?  In what setting is 1 second = 6 minutes?  (I assume you are not traveling at warp speed and comparing time in the spacecraft to time on earth).

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation.  I am tracking time for my company.  The company says that time is to be tracked in 6 minute intervals.  So if I work on something for 3 minutes, that is rounded up to 0.1.  if I work on something for a second, that is also rounded up to 0.1.  If I do exactly 6 minutes of work on something, that is 0.1.  0.1 represents 10% of an hour (6 minutes).  I just want to round up to the nearest interval.  Make sense?  Thank you.

Comment: I believe he is rounding up like in billing - e.g. time is charged by the next largest six minutes or percentage of an hour (the six minutes stuff is really just confusing the issue - if 10% = six minutes, then 10% = 0.1 of an hour, so just fractions of an hour is what is needed).

Comment: I used to program a timeclock system for a living so I understand :) We allowed all types of rounding (some companies round back after the hour, round forwards before the hour, on 15 minute intervals, etc.)

Comment: Yes NetMage is exactly right.  Sorry for my poor wording.  Thanks to both of you for the help!

Comment: @WordpressUser  Ok. That makes sense now.  You want to `ROUNDUP` any time interval to tenths of an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula is:

```
=ROUNDUP(A1*24, 1)
```

Intervals (time) in Excel are stored as fractions of a 24 hour day, so converting the day fraction to an hour fraction just means multiplying by 24.

Comment: Thanks so much NetMage.  I upvoted you but it said I didn't have enough points to make it public.  I just tried your solution and it worked great.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

`=ROUNDUP(A1*24, 1)` won't work in OpenOffice Calc nor in some configurations of Google Sheets and Excel, but

```
=ROUNDUP(A1*24;1)
```

will (in OpenOffice Calc and *some* configurations of Google Sheets and Excel).